# Java. Как найти объект в ArrayList'е?

Tags: java

Задание создать ArrayList с продуктами, у которых есть название, id, и количество. А затем осуществить поиск по части названия и вывести подходящие продукты.

Comment: Только перебором.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
```

Далее заполняете ваш лист вашими продуктами. После заполнения осуществляете поиск по вашему запросу (Допустим в названии (title) должно содержаться слово 'hello') и собираете все подходящие продукты в новый список:

```
List<Product> results = products.stream().filter( c -> c.getTitle().contains("hello")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```